# Pre-define CSS background image center center position and cover background size

Tags: css, background-image, background-position, background-size

I am struggling to shorten down my CSS code for background image position (center center) and background size (cover).

Whenever I use the following code, it works fine, obviously:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner-divider" id="banner-divider-welcome"></div>
<div class="banner-divider" id="banner-divider-second"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner-divider{
width: 100%;
height:600px;
}
#banner-divider-welcome{
background: url(/images/welcome.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#banner-divider-second{
background: url(/images/second.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I would like to shorten/delete multiple CSS repetitions of the center center and cover properties (as I have multiple banner ID's but with repeating background settings), however the following code does not center center and cover the images correctly:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner-divider" id="banner-divider-welcome"></div>
<div class="banner-divider" id="banner-divider-second"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner-divider{
width: 100%;
height:600px;
background: #fff;
background-image: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat
background-position: center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#banner-divider-welcome{
background: url(/images/welcome.jpg); 
}
#banner-divider-second{
background: url(/images/second.jpg); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're overwriting the entire `background` property. Set `background-image` instead.

```
.banner-divider{
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    background: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* <- missing semi-colon */
    background-position: center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#banner-divider-welcome{
    background-image: url(/images/welcome.jpg); /* <- here */ 
}
#banner-divider-second{
    background-image: url(/images/second.jpg);  /* <- and here */
}
```

```css
.banner-divider{
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    background: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#banner-divider-welcome{
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/100/100/any);
}
#banner-divider-second{
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/150/150/any);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-divider" id="banner-divider-welcome"></div>
<div class="banner-divider" id="banner-divider-second"></div>
```

Comment: it does not work, the image is not aligned center center in the div, but top left

Answer (score 1):

you need to use background-image instead of using background property.

```
.banner-divider{
width: 100%;
height:600px;
background: #fff;
background-image: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#banner-divider-welcome{
background-image: url(/images/welcome.jpg); 
}
#banner-divider-second{
background-image: url(/images/second.jpg); 
}
```

Comment: it does not work, the image is not aligned center center in the div, but top left

Comment: no need to mention `background-position: center center; ` just make it `background-position: center; `

Comment: try removing `background-position: center;`

Comment: i know its irritating now but i need to solve this now if you can create a fiddle link for it.

Comment: now this is funny its a very small mistake..focus on your css on line `background-repeat: no-repeat` the problem is `;` is not there add `;` its fine

Comment: bahaha omg ! such a stupid mistake ! really sorry to waste your time on this, but your effort is gladly appreciated !! thank you !

Comment: @rainerbrunotte with css it is usually something stupid like this ;)